# How does dask know variable states before it runs map_partitions?

Tags: python, dask, directed-acyclic-graphs, dask-distributed, dask-dataframe

In the dask code below I set x with 1 and 2 right before executing two `map_partitions`. The result seems fine, however I don't fully understand it.

If dask waits to run the two `map_partitions` only when it finds the `compute()`, and at the time it finds the `compute()` x is 2, how dask knows that x = 1 in the first `map_partitions`?

```
pdf = pd.DataFrame({
    'id': [1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 4, 1, 2, 2, 1],
    'balance': [150, 140, 130, 280, 260, 220, 230, 330, 420, 120, 210]
})    
ddf = dd.from_pandas(pdf, npartitions=2) 
    
def func(df, a):
    return a

x = 1
ddf['should_be_1'] = ddf.map_partitions(func, x,  meta='int')

x = 2
ddf['should_be_2'] = ddf.map_partitions(func, x,  meta='int')

ddf.compute()

    id  balance should_be_1 should_be_2
0   1   150     1           2
1   1   140     1           2
2   1   130     1           2
3   2   280     1           2
4   2   260     1           2
5   3   220     1           2
6   4   230     1           2
7   1   330     1           2
8   2   420     1           2
9   2   120     1           2
10  1   210     1           2
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The computations are delayed, however dask keeps track of the values of the arguments passed to the delayed functions. Changing value of an argument later will not change the value passed to an earlier delayed computation:

```py
from dask import delayed

@delayed
def f(x):
    return x

x = 1
a = f(x)

x = 2
b = f(x)

print(dict(a.dask))
# {'some_hash': (<function f at 0x7fab1b72c550>, 1)}

print(dict(b.dask))
# {'some_hash': (<function f at 0x7fab1b72c550>, 2)}
```